# PHP work with Wordpress database and own database

Tags: php, html, wordpress, mysqli

I want to copy Wordpress database in a different environment. So, I have built my own environment where I want to view submitted forms and import into my own database. So there is a form database in Wordpress that works with 2 tables, but I don't really know how to work properly with meta_value.

In the first table (items) "id" and "name" are stored.

```
|  id  |  name  |
  613     Mark
```

In the 2nd table (item_metas) "item_id", "field_id" and "meta_value" are stored. "item_id" is the same as "id" in the other table

```
|  id  | meta_value | field_id | item_id |
  5620      Audi         96         613
  5619      Diesel       95         613
  5618      Neve         94         613
  5617      Maybe        93         613
  5616      Yes          92         613
  5615      Do it        91         613
  5614      Bike         90         613
  5613      Car          89         613
  5612      Wipe         88         613
```

Is it possible and how to inset these data into an other database with a move action like this:

```
INSERT INTO other_database (name, car, petrol) SELECT name, meta_value, meta_value FROM item_metas WHERE id = 613;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure exactly of the purpose of those tables, but want to use them in a different or local environment I would dump the data using mysql dump and import directly into your new database.

From CLI:

```
 mysqldump -u username -p db_name items items_metas > dump.sql
```

then

```
mysql -u username -p db_name < dump.sql
```